# Working of ioctl(2)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, system-calls

Please explain to me the working of the `ioctl(2)` system call.
The manual page and wikipedia are neither very informative nor detailed.

What should the file descriptor that is passed as the first argument of `ioctl(2)` be pointing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the device you want to manipulate before calling `ioctl`. Then you pass the file descriptor for the device you want to manipulate as the first parameter. You would only call `ioctl` when there's some particular device that has some particular manipulation that you want to perform on it.

Comment: Every device on your system. Have a look at the files in `/dev`.